# Masstransit Testharness with multiple ExecuteActivities doesn't create Endpoints as expected

Tags: masstransit

I want to write a test that checks if my routingslip works as expected. I narrowed it down to this simplified Version.

```
namespace MasstransitTest
{
    public class Tests
    {
        private readonly InMemoryTestHarness _harness;

        public Tests()
        {

            var services = new ServiceCollection();

            services.AddLogging(builder => builder.AddConsole().SetMinimumLevel(LogLevel.Debug));

            services.AddMassTransitInMemoryTestHarness(cfg =>
            {
                cfg.AddExecuteActivity<ActivityOne, MyMessage>()
                    .Endpoint(c => c.Name = "queue1");
                
                cfg.AddExecuteActivity<ActivityTwo, MyMessage>()
                    .Endpoint(c => c.Name = "queue2");
            });

            var serviceProvider = services.BuildServiceProvider(true);
            _harness = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<InMemoryTestHarness>();
            _harness.Start();
        }

        [Test]
        public async Task Test1()
        {
            var routingSlipBuilder = new RoutingSlipBuilder(Guid.NewGuid());
            routingSlipBuilder.AddActivity("Activity1", new Uri("loopback://localhost/queue1"), new { MyMessage = new MyMessage()});
            routingSlipBuilder.AddActivity("Activity2", new Uri("loopback://localhost/queue2"), new { MyMessage = new MyMessage()});
            routingSlipBuilder.AddSubscription(new Uri("loopback://localhost/protocol-event-monitor"),RoutingSlipEvents.All, RoutingSlipEventContents.All);
            var routingSlip = routingSlipBuilder.Build();

            await _harness.Bus.Execute(routingSlip);

            Assert.That(await _harness.Sent.Any<RoutingSlipCompleted>());
        }
    }
}
```

This Test failes, but it works if I replace one of the activities by an activity with another argument type. For example

```
 cfg.AddExecuteActivity<ActivityTwo, MyOtherMessage>().Endpoint(c => c.Name = "queue2");
```

The failing test prints this log:

> info: MassTransit[0] Configured endpoint queue2, Execute Activity: MasstransitTest.ActivityOne
> info: MassTransit[0] Configured endpoint queue2, Execute Activity: MasstransitTest.ActivityTwo
> dbug: MassTransit[0] Starting bus: loopback://localhost/

I think the Problem is that only one endpoint gets configured, but I don't know why. Is this a bug in the Testingframework?

Comment: The `.Endpoint()` connects via the `IExecuteActivity<T>`, so if two activities have the same argument type, they'll end up with the same endpoint configuration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using `.Endpoint` to override the execute or compensate endpoint for an activity, the *arguments* or *log* type must be unique.

To change the endpoint name for activities that have a common argument or log type, use an `ActivityDefinition` or an `ExecuteActivityDefinition`

```csharp
public class ActivityOnExecuteActivityDefinition :
    ExecuteActivityDefinition<ActivityOne, One>
{
    public ActivityOnExecuteActivityDefinition()
    {
        EndpointName = "queue1";
    }
}
```